# Seeking the algorithm to generate this table of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm looking for a way to generate the following the series of numbers given the version number on the left. For example, given "2", generate [6, 18]. The series of numbers is from [here](http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/alignment-pattern-locations/).

```
 V2  6  18
 V3  6  22
 V4  6  26
 V5  6  30
 V6  6  34
 V7  6  22  38
 V8  6  24  42
 V9  6  26  46
V10  6  28  50
V11  6  30  54
V12  6  32  58
V13  6  34  62
V14  6  26  46  66
V15  6  26  48  70
V16  6  26  50  74
V17  6  30  54  78
V18  6  30  56  82
V19  6  30  58  86
V20  6  34  62  90
V21  6  28  50  72   94
V22  6  26  50  74   98
V23  6  30  54  78  102
V24  6  28  54  80  106
V25  6  32  58  84  110
V26  6  30  58  86  114
V27  6  34  62  90  118
V28  6  26  50  74   98  122
V29  6  30  54  78  102  126
V30  6  26  52  78  104  130
V31  6  30  56  82  108  134
V32  6  34  60  86  112  138
V33  6  30  58  86  114  142
V34  6  34  62  90  118  146
V35  6  30  54  78  102  126  150
V36  6  24  50  76  102  128  154
V37  6  28  54  80  106  132  158
V38  6  32  58  84  110  136  162
V39  6  26  54  82  110  138  166
V40  6  30  58  86  114  142  170
```

To give context to what these numbers actually are, here is a quote from the specification (ISO-18004) from which they were originally drawn:

> The Alignment Patterns are positioned symmetrically on either side of
>   the diagonal running from the top left corner of the symbol to the
>   bottom right corner. They are spaced as evenly as possible between the
>   Timing Pattern and the opposite side of the symbol, any uneven spacing
>   being accommodated between the Timing Pattern and the first Alignment
>   Pattern in the symbol interior.

So, there was an original method/algorithm that generated these numbers.

I've come up with the following Python code which generates the correct sequences, but contains an "exceptional" condition for V32, expressed in the `if` statement.

```
import math

def pattern(ver):
    w = 21 + ((ver - 1) * 4)       # Width
    h = 6                          # First item
    t = (w - 1) - 6                # Last item
    r = t - h                      # Distance between first and last
    n = math.ceil(r/28)            # Number of items in list - 1

    if (w == 145):
        intervals = 26             # Anomaly
    else:
        intervals = math.ceil(r/n) # Ceiling to nearest multiple of 2
        intervals = intervals + (intervals % 2)

    xs = [t]
    for m in (n-1) * [intervals]: xs.append(xs[-1] - m)
    xs.append(h)
    return list(reversed(xs))

for n in range(2, 41):
    print("Version {:2d}: {}".format(n, pattern(n)))
```

I'm looking for an algorithm where the magic branch & value is not needed. The algorithm might not exist, but I'm hopeful.

Comment: This is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com as you are looking for improvement on existing code (and are not facing a problem).

Comment: My problem is that I have not actually found the algorithm that generates the code without exceptional special magic values.

Comment: From the webpage looks like that table is a fixed arbitrary set of constants.

Comment: It's not arbitrary. They are positions for "alignment patterns" in QR codes optimally, equally spaced apart.

Comment: [See the answer of *Calculating QRCode Alignment Patterns positions*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21369651/440302).  If that answers your question, I would advise closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: FYI, it seems that the duplicate question's answer also has a similar bug. Where as my calculation of V32 is incorrect and needs magic adjustment, his calculation of V36 is also incorrect.